# TypeError: Cannot read property 'sendNotification' of undefined in Angular 8

Tags: javascript, angular, angular8

I have a service AppRestService  with following methods:

```js
export class AppRestService implements OnDestroy {
  private readonly onDestroy = new Subject<void>();
  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private sessSvc: SessionActivityService) { }
  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.onDestroy.next();
  }
  getData(route: string): Observable<any> {
    this.sessSvc.sendNotification("TEST works", 15);
    return this.http.get<any>(route).pipe(
      takeUntil(this.onDestroy),
      catchError(this.errorHandler),
    );
  }
  errorHandler(err: HttpErrorResponse) {
    let restErr: IErrorObjHttp = new ErrorObjHttp();
    restErr.errObj = err;
    if (err.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
      restErr.type = "client";
      restErr.message = `An error occurred: ${err.error.message}.`;    // Client-side error
    } else {
      restErr.type = "server";
      restErr.message = `Server returned code : ${err.status}, error message is ${err.message}.`;    // Service-side error
    }
   
    console.log("Error:", restErr);
    this.sessSvc.sendNotification(restErr.message, 15);
    console.log("post-sendNotification():", restErr.message);
    return throwError(restErr);
  }
}
```

I am calling this service from different components. The problem is "this.sessSvc" ( which is another service that is called within this service to send notification) is undefined in the errorHandler() method and is giving error. errorHandler() method  is called from the getData() method.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'sendNotification' of undefined
```

But it is working fine when "this.sessSvc" called directly in the getData() method and is able to `sendNotification`. What am I missing?

This is how I call the service from a different component

```js
export class PlanComponent implements OnInit {
  planList: any;
  constructor(private service: AppRestService) { }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.planList = this.service.getData("/api/plans/hhjkhhk");
  }
}
```

Comment: Two points, where do you provide the service? At root? Also, in your `PlanComponent`, do you at some point use an async-pipe on `planList`? Without a subscribe somewhere down the line `getData` will never actually execute.

Comment: And I haven't tried it how you did it, but I'd to `catchError` like this: `catchError(error => this.errorHandler(error))`

Comment: Just curious, if you use this style of declaring the function, will it work?

`errorHandler=(err: HttpErrorResponse)=> {
     ...
  }
}`

Comment: @GunnarB.```<ng-container *ngFor="let plan of (planList | async)">``` Yes using async pipe on the html of the PlanComponent

Comment: @DJBurb Yes it is working fine unless for this partcular issue

Comment: @GunnarB. Wow actually that worked changing catchError. Can you post it as an answer so i can accept it? but curious can you explain ur answer why would u do that way? i am learning. Thanks for ur help .

Comment: yash provided an answer with a good explanation, mark that one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
catchError(this.errorHandler)
```

This can be:

```js
catchError(this.errorHandler.bind(this))
```

Or:

```js
catchError(error => this.errorHandler(error)) // as Gunnar pointed
```

It is because `this` context inside the `errorHandler` becomes the function itself and not the `AppRestService`.

But `Arrow functions` do not bind their own this, instead, they inherit the one from the parent scope.

Also, the `bind()` method creates a new function that, when called, has its this keyword set to the provided value, with a given sequence of arguments preceding any provided when the new function is called.

**Some references:**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind

https://www.codementor.io/@dariogarciamoya/understanding-this-in-javascript-with-arrow-functions-gcpjwfyuc